# What is the relationship between namespace and lexical scope?

Tags: javascript

From my understanding lexical scope is a subset of the name space. What is the relationship between namespace and lexical scope?

Comment: JavaScript does not have a real concept of "namespaces". Namespaces are just implemented with nested objects. So their relationship is the same relationship as objects with scope have (none?).

Comment: There are no namespaces that include scopes in javascript.

Comment: [Everything you wanted to know about JavaScript scope](http://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) - covers what a namespace is and isn't in there also.  It's also on the first page of google results for your question title.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: That article doesn't really cover what the term "namespace" is usually used for in JS. The phrase "*the namespace is sometimes an interchangable word*" is the best part of it.

Comment: @Bergi Namespaces are mentioned further down also - I think it covers off what they are (not really anything in JS other than obects, as Felix mentions above)

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Yeah, I've read that, but I think it's confusing to newbies. He gives an example of the module pattern and then says "heres my namespace". No explanation what namespaces *are*.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are organisational units of code. Typically they are implemented in JavaScript by using properties on object literals, but there are more complicated implementations.

Simple example:

```
var myApp = {}; // Root 'namespace'.
myApp.services = {}; // 'Namespace' for service constructor functions.
myApp.controllers = {}; // 'Namespace' for controller constructor functions.

myApp.controllers.UserController = function() { /* ... */ };

// Usage.
var userController = new myApp.controllers.UserController();
```

Lexical scope is a completely orthogonal concept and relates the the visibility of variables within a piece of code. Scope is defined by functions in JavaScript. Very modern implementations of JavaScript also include mechanisms for block scoping, but you will not see this used very often in the wild.

Example:

```
function f() {
  var x = 'foo';
}

console.log(x); // undefined because the scope of x is the function f.
```